# Presenting a childViewController of a viewController by "presentViewController" causes error?

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

1. There is a `viewController` here. In its `addChildViewController` function, I add a `tableViewController` as its child.
2. Now, what we can see is the `viewController's`, but I want to show the `tableViewController's tableView`. I achieve this by:

   `[viewController presentViewController:tableViewController animate:YES xxx:xxx]`
3. What I do in the 2nd step trigger some error：`“Application tried to present modally an active controller.”`

So the question is:

1. If I want to show a view of the `childViewController` of a `viewController`, couldn't I use `presentViewController` function?
2. If so, why?
3. How could I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot for reading and answering. I've hunt for the reason for days.

Comment: When you add a controller as a child, you also have to add that controller's view as a subview of the parent controller's view. You should not call `presentViewController:animated:`. You should read Apple's document, "Creating Custom Container View Controllers".

Comment: @rdelmar   thx a lot ! i've read the document,and that do me a big favor！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what gives you a clue for the answer "Application tried to present modally an **active** controller。"

There are two solutions:

1.Instead of using `presentViewController`, you should use `addSubview` like this:

```
[viewController.view addSubview:tableViewController.view];
```

2.Instead of using `addChildViewController`:

```
// [viewController addChildViewController:tableViewController];
[viewController.view presentViewController:tableViewController animate:YES completion:nil];
```